# remove novalidate in form tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application I have a form which submits data to the database.

I noticed that my jquery validation was not working and when when I do 'View Source' I found `novalidate="novalidate"`in the form tag.

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" action="/subapp_test/books/create_sub_book"  id="new_book" method="post" onsubmit="validateBook();">
.....
```

How do I disable it?

Here is the rails code of the form:

```
<% remote_form_for @book, :url => { :controller => "books", :action => "create_sub_book", :id =>params[:id] }, :html => { :onsubmit => "validateBook();"} do |f| %>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
:onsubmit => "return validateform();"}
```

mark `return` there..

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I don't understand why novalidate has been added to the code though